# Eclipse debug mode hangs/fails

Tags: eclipse, debugging, freeze

When I run my program in RUN mode, it's working, but in DEBUG mode, the program is hanging, and after a long time, failing. I have this problem with both eclipse Neon and Photon.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the breakpoints in DEBUG perspective, and it finally worked!